# Hibernate does kill my Java architecture?

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, architecture, entity-relationship

I have read this great [article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/) by Mkyong about **one-to-many relationship in Hibernate** and I have a big doubt. Mkyong uses two clase in his example: `Stock.java and StockDailyRecord.java`

I think the **class diagram** has to be: *"A stock has many stockdialyrecords"* and therefore as **database entities diagram** has to be: *"stock one-to-many stockdialyrecords"*.

But Mkyong has gone further, and here is where appear my doubt. He set an attribute named `Stock stock on the StockDialyRecords class`. That said, he create a **bidireccional relationship**. This is right? I understand that this way for ORM, we can walk in both directions. But from **Diagram class** point of view is like it says: *"A Stock has many StockDialyRecords and a StockDialyRecords has a Stock"*

I say it from point of view of the concept of architecture. Is like it is a cycle or paradoxical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bidirectional as it represents two different relationships:

- stock *has many* records (one-to-many)
- record *references* stock (many-to-ony)

Both relationships have sense from business perspective. The latter seems even more important - each record *must* have a reference to a stock it describes.

From technical perspective bidirectional relationship has some advantages, e.g. it allows you to build queries from both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should definitely have a many to one, linking back as a one to many as Hibernate will manage the relationships for you and avoid any issues. You don't need to if you don't want to, but it means you might need some extra coding.

Comment: I "disagree" with bohemian unless I missed the question, as I think his point misses the OP's point.